# "Create Catalog" is greyed out in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm try to create catalog in SSIS but when right clicking on `Integration Services Catalogs`, the `Create Catalog` is greyed out.

It is a SQL server 2017 Developer edition.

[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Is it possible that the SSIS check box was not selected during the installation of the instance?

Comment: I did not install SSIS but I see them available in SQL Server Configuration Wizard. Plus, there is also one Catalog available from past. So SSIS must be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

I had already one SSIS Catalog created so it does not allow creation of more than one Catalog hence the option is greyed out.